# How do I access Stripe.js elements with a React router app?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement Stripe.js elements into the Checkout component of my React app that uses react-router, but I can't seem to render the elements at all. Here is my root component setup:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import {CSSTransition, TransitionGroup} from "react-transition-group";
import Header from "./Header";
import Register from "./Register";
import RegisterConfirmed from "./RegisterConfirmed";
import Login from "./Login";
import Option from "./Option";
import Lookup from "./Lookup";
import Payment from "./Payment";
import Profile from "./Profile";
import Service from "./Service";
import Checkout from "./Checkout";

import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.PUBLISHABLE_KEY);

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
            <Header />
            <Route render={({location}) => (
            <TransitionGroup>
                <CSSTransition
                    key={location.key}
                    timeout={450}
                    classNames="fade"
                >
                    <Switch location={location}>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Option}></Route>
                        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}></Route>
                        <Route exact path="/registerconfirmed" component={RegisterConfirmed}></Route>
                        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}></Route>
                        <Route exact path="/option" component={Option}></Route>
                        <Route exact path="/lookup" component={Lookup}></Route>
                        <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile}></Route>
                        <Route exact path="/service" component={Service}></Route>
                        <Route exact path="/checkout" component={Checkout}></Route>
                        <Route exact path="/payment" component={Payment}></Route>
                        <Route exact path="/checkout" component={Checkout}></Route>
                    </Switch>
                </CSSTransition>
            </TransitionGroup>
            )} />
            </Elements>
        </div>
    );
};


export default App;
```

And here is how I am trying to access the CardElement on my Checkout component:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import { Link, Switch, Route, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import ArrowBackIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowBack';
import { CardElement, Elements, useElements, useStripe } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

function Checkout(props) {
    const history = useHistory();

    const [emailAddress, setEmailAddress] = useState("");

    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();


    function handleEmailInput(event) {
        setEmailAddress(event.target.value);
    }

    return (
    <div className="page-container">
        <h1 className="page-header">Checkout</h1>
        <label className="lookup-label">Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" className="lookup-input" onChange={handleEmailInput}/>
            <p>User ID: {userID}</p>
            <p>fullName: {fullName}</p>
            <p>subtotalBeforeDiscount: {subtotalBeforeDiscount}</p>
        <div className="stripe-form">
        <form>
            <CardElement />
            <button type="submit" disabled={!stripe}>
                Pay
            </button>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div className="lookup-footer">
            <button
                className="back-button"
                onClick={() => history.push("/payment")}>
                <ArrowBackIcon></ArrowBackIcon>
            </button>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default Checkout;
```

Can someone please tell me what I am missing? I can't find any clear instructions for implementing Stripe.js with react router.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example that should prove helpful here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-stripe-js-q1loc

Comment: The example you provided is for nested routing. How would we do it if we are not implementing nested routing?